# z-index is not working for fixed position element

Tags: html, css

I have designed a footer which will be fixed position only on mobile resolution.but it looks like z-index not working for that div.
 following is the code of html and CSS

```
<div class="cws_social_links-icon  animated fadeIn">
    <a href="//facebook.com" class="icon_link"><i data-font-color="#ffffff" data-bg-color="#3b5998" class="cws_fa flaticon-facebook55 fa-lg custom_colors square kill_gradient" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(59, 89, 152); border-color: rgb(59, 89, 152);"></i></a>
    <a href="//twitter.com" class="icon_link"><i data-font-color="#ffffff" data-bg-color="#55acee" class="cws_fa flaticon-twitter1 fa-lg custom_colors square kill_gradient" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(85, 172, 238); border-color: rgb(85, 172, 238);"></i></a>
    <a href="//linkedin.com" class="icon_link"><i data-font-color="#ffffff" data-bg-color="#28A6EC" class="cws_fa fa fa-linkedin fa-lg custom_colors square kill_gradient" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(40, 166, 236); border-color: rgb(40, 166, 236);"></i></a>
     <p></p>
</div>
<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 479px)
    main.css?ver=4.7.2:9100
    .cws_social_links-icon {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: left;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 20px;
        z-index: 0;
        height: 60px;
        width: 90%;
    }
</style>
```

[example-z-index not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0AEY.png)

Please see the social media icons at the bottom of the image, it is disappearing under the content.I have given z-index to social media icons.but it is not working.

Comment: what do you mean not working? do you want it above all (topmost)?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle ?

Comment: btw, set a background to avoid transparent effect, this will give you a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: Please see the image.Please see the social media icons at the bottom, it is disappearing under the content.

Comment: Like others said, you should provide CSS of other elements. Without it it's difficult to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` property takes a numeric value that acts like a layer position on the `z` axis.

The element with the highest `z-index` value will be seen first, then the element with the next highest value, and so on.

Therefore, a `z-index: 0` property will NOT put it above your body content. Try using `1` or `2` as values. (Avoid using big, high numbers as it's much harder to maintain).

Also, [read more about this property at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Without context of other css definitions, the behaviour of your z-index is hard to evaluate.

You assigned a z-index of 0 to the social media icons div. As it appears on your screen shot, the are in the "background". A z-index higher than zero (in fact, higher than the z-index of the other elements) will put it to the front - and that, I guess, is what you are trying to achieve.

...but don't use numbers as high as thousands, those are hard to maintain later on.

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve, what you exactly guess. I changed to 1 to 100, still not working.

Comment: It would be great if you could create a fiddle or codepen or anything like that, containing the whole relevant code. Without the other css definitions, all of our answers are based on guessing.

Comment: thanks for suggesting me ,but it content code of entire website.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this,

```
.cws_social_links-icon {z-index: 999999;}
```

Comment: add any background-color:#ffffff;  too

Comment: Please, ***don't*** leave any code like this. Perhaps it could be useful to see if something else has a higher `z-index`, but if that isn't the issue its much better to use low numbers.